# Why is this StringTemplates with custom delimiters not working?

Tags: java, template-engine, stringtemplate

I'm trying to use String Template with custom delimiters.

This code snippet:

```
new ST("Hello @what@", '@', '@').add("what", "world").render()
```

throws `org.stringtemplate.v4.compiler.STException`, so I'm obviously doing it wrong.

If I change it to `new ST("Hello $what$", '$', '$')`, it works. Why is `@` not working?

**Edit** - I tried other characters besides `$` and `@`, and nothing but `$` works so far. What's going on?

Comment: What version? Can you reproduce the stack trace please? And include a SSCCE (http://sscce.org/) please.

Comment: @I82Much Latest version ... 4.0.2 ... odd, I thought the example above is a SSCCE. Doesn't it reproduce? If not, I can prepare a more complete example.

Answer (score 0):

Characters like '$', '<' are special for StringTemplate and need to be escaped.

You can make a escape util like:

```
ST st = new ST(StringUtility.escapeStringTemplate(str));

//utility function

public static String escapeStringTemplate(String str){
    String result = str;
    if (result.contains("<")) {
        result = result.replace("<", "\\<");
    }
    if (result.contains("$")) {
        result = result.replace("$", "\\$");
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe they have to be different characters; start/stop.
Ter

Comment: If that's the case, shouldn't the constructor throw an illegal argument exception if they're not both the same?

Comment: From the ASCII range 0x21..0x7E the following chars could be used as both the start- and end-delimiters: `< > ? \ ^ \` } ~ # $ % ' * + -` (the others, `! " & ( ) , . / : ; = @ [ ] _ { | a..z A..Z 0..9`, could not)

Comment: @BartKiers post this as an answer - this should be the accepted answer.
Where did you find this information?  And thanks!